# How can a later run of my program use information from a previous run, and how do I change a line of a text file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm having some trouble with a program. I must delete/modify certain lines in a text file. The program is like a database, it stores names, ages, and registration numbers of people. I have tried everything.

```
form2.info.Lines.Add('Nr. ordine ' +Inttostr(numar)+ ' ');
form2.mmo1.Lines.Add('Nr.ordine' +Inttostr(numar)+ ' ');
form2.mmo1.Lines.Add('Nume: ' +nume+ ' ');
form2.mmo1.Lines.Add('Prenume: ' +prenume+ ' ');
```

1. Each time I close my program, the registration number is always 1 and I want it to be continued from where I left it. How can I do it?
2. How can I modify a specific line in my text?

Comment: Save the number when the program closes, and load it when it opens. To modify specific lines, load the entire text file, modify the line, and save the entire file.

Comment: I'm using a Memo in which my info is shown .

Comment: You are calling mmo1.Lines.SaveToFile before you close your app, y/n?

Comment: Yes ,  SaveToFile to save and LoadFromFile to load

Comment: Btw, downvoter(s): This q and its answer will help many new Delphi users - I get the impression from qs here that many are using training materials that set v. similar tasks to the one the OP is evidently at.  It got a useful answer within 10 minutes of being posted, so can it really have been that bad?  Surely, the better thing to do would be to leave it be or even upvote so that it stands a chance of catching their eyes?  More, competent Delphi coders is surely not a bad thing ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to save your last registration number to a text file and retrieve it at startup. If you do not want to store it separately, you could load the whole file and look for the latest registration number.

To modify or read a specified line in memo you can use line index:

```
form2.mmo1.Lines.Strings[0] := 'This is line 0';
```

I would suggest you to store your 'database' in [TStringGrid](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Grids.TStringGrid)